# Очистить выборочно инпуты в форме

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input id=\"datepicker1\" type=\"text\" name=\"van1\" size=\"10\" ><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"van.reset()\">Очистить</button>
<input id=\"datepicker2\" type=\"text\" name=\"van2\" size=\"10\" ><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"van.reset()\">Очистить</button>
<input id=\"datepicker3\" type=\"text\" name=\"van3\" size=\"10\" ><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"van.reset()\">Очистить</button>
<input id=\"datepicker4\" type=\"text\" name=\"van4\" size=\"10\" ><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"van.reset()\">Очистить</button>
<input  id=\"datepicker5\" type=\"text\" name=\"van5\" size=\"10\" ><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"van.reset()\">Очистить</button>
```

Как очищать поля выборочно, при нажатии на кнопку очистить рядом с нужным полем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input id=\"datepicker1\" type=\"text\" name=\"van1\" size=\"10\" ><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"clearInput('datepicker1')\">Очистить</button>
function clearInput(id) {
        try{
            document.querySelector('#' + id).value = '';
        }catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
```